# Groupby 2 columns and find .min of multiple other columns (python pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data frame looks like this:

```
|Months   |  Places | Sales_X |   Sales_Y |  Sales_Z |
|----------------------------------------------------|
|**month1 |  Place1 | 10000   |   12000   |  13000   |
|month1   |  Place2 |  300    |     200   |   1000   |
|month1   |  Place3 |  350    |    1000   |  1200**  | 
|month2   |  Place2 |  1400   |    12300  |  14000   |
|month2   |  Place3 |  9000   |    8500   |    150   |
|month2   |  Place1 |  90     |    4000   |   3000   |
|month3   |  Place2 |  12350  |    8590   |   4000   |
|month3   |  Place1 | 4500    |    7020   |   8800   |
|month3   |  Place3 |  351    |    6500   |   4567   |
```

---

I need to find the highest number from the three sales columns by month and show the name of the place with the highest number.

I have been trying to solve it by using pandas.DataFrame.idxmax and groupby but it does not seem to work.

I created a new df with the highest number/row which may help

```
|Months  |  Places  |  Highest_sales|
|-----------------------------------|
|**month1|   Place1 |    10000      |
|month1  |   Place2 |      200      |
|month1  |   Place3 |      350**    |
|        |          |               |
|**month2|   Place2 |     1400      |
|month2  |   Place3 |      150      |
|month2  |   Place1 |      90**     |
|        |          |               |
|**month3|  Place2  |     4000      |
|month3  |  Place1  |     4500      |
|month3  |   Place3 |     351**     |
|-----------------------------------|
```

Now I just need the highest number/ month and the name of the place. When using groupby on two columns and getting the min of the Lowest_sales, the result

```
df.groupby(['Months', 'Places'])['Highest_sales'].max()
```

when I run this

```
Months  Places        Highest Sales

1       Place1          1549.0
        Place2          2214.0
        Place3          2074.0
                    ...  
12      Place1          1500.0
        Place2          8090.0
        Place3          2074.0
```

the format I am looking for would be

```
|**Months|Places                    |Highest Sales**|
|--------|--------------------------|---------------|
|Month1  |Place(*of highest sales*) |100000         |
|Month2  |Place(*of highest sales*) |900000         |
|Month3  |Place(*of highest sales*) |3232000        |
|Month4  |Place(*of highest sales*) |1300833        |
|....    |                          |               |
|Month12 |Place(*of highest sales*) |               |
-----------------------------------------------------

12 rows and 3 columns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for `Sales` columns, create `Highest` column adn then aggregate [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) only for `Months` and select rows and columns by list in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
#columns with substring Sales
df1 = df.filter(like='Sales')
#or all columns from third position
#df1 = df.iloc[: 2:]

df['Highest'] = df1.min(axis=1)
df = df.loc[df.groupby('Months')['Highest'].idxmax(), ['Months','Places','Highest']]

print (df)
   Months  Places  Highest
0  month1  Place1    10000
3  month2  Place2     1400
7  month3  Place1     4500
```

Comment: this solution seems to have the same problem I encountered.

Comment: for the places it just picks a place say Place1 and displays it for the whole data frame. All else is correct.

Comment: @morvaybalazs - Can you be more specific? What is wrong?

Comment: @morvaybalazs - My problem is in each your sample data are different numbers. Is possible add expected output from first data sample? Mainly column `Places` and `Highest` ?

Comment: The issue is: the output shows the correct week and the highest sale, but when it comes to the place it just groups it by one place. Basically, for every highest sale, there is a place it occurred. In the output, these do not seem to be linked.

Comment: `In the output, these do not seem to be linked.` - so `Place1` is Higest value for `month1`, so it is linked.  Not understand, so ask for expected ouput.

Comment: @morvaybalazs - or need all rows? By `df = df.loc[df.groupby('Months')['Highest'].transform('max').eq(df['Highest']), 
            ['Months','Places','Highest']]` ? Because `idxmax` get only first maximal row.

Comment: yes as I have shown in the second table, I need the highest number of a cross-section.  1 month has 3 places out of that there is a max number. I need to turn this into one row that shows the months the place that produced the highest number and the highest number itself.

Comment: the second solution has an issue with the places as well: KeyError: "['Places'] not in index". If I delete the places from the code it works fine.

Comment: @morvaybalazs - I found problem, need `min` instead `max` in `df1.min(axis=1)`. If `KeyError` it means there is no column `Places`, what is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ? Maybe typo or different columkn name

Comment: df['Highest'] = df1.min(axis=1) this code takes into account the week column as well as the sales and sets it as the smallest number.

Comment: @055931-YT14 what is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: ['month', 'place', 'highest']

Comment: @055931-YT14 - so it means thre is column `place`, not `Places`.  So change `['Months','Places','Highest']` to `['month','place','highest']`

Comment: @055931-YT14 - hmmm, problem is with data in question? Or with real data?

Comment: Thank you very much! All good now :) I had a problem with the real data.  You were correct from the beginning.